# Breaking a MultiDimensional Array into a Single Dimension

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have fields in mySQL which is currently being stored like this under the field "tags"

```
Shopping|Health & Beauty
Coffee|Shopping
```

What I'm trying to do is to loop through this to create a single dimension array and to grab only the unique values.

I have my query selecting DISTINCT tags from TABLE and run the loop like this:

```
    while ($row_tags = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_tags)) { 
    $tags = $row_tags['tags'];
    $imploded_tags[] = explode("|",$tags);
    }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($imploded_tags);
```

The result from the print_r is showing it as a multidimensional array. I've tried to reexplode it and implode it in different ways, but I haven't been able to get any success. Is there a way that I can create this into a single dimension array? Not all tags will have an equal amount of tags separated by |, so I can't seem to get it to go with a function that I tried from another StackOverflow post. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Shopping
            [1] => Health & Beauty

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Coffee
            [1] => Shopping
        )
```

Comment: So is what you are looking for, just an unique array of all tags in the system? Can you show your SQL query and explain your database structure? Do you have a tags table that you can get this data from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
while ($row_tags = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_tags)) { 
$tags = $row_tags['tags'];
$tags = explode("|",$tags);
 foreach($tags as $v){
  $imploded_tags[] = $v;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
         $imploded_tags = array_merge(explode("|",$tags), $imploded_tags);
    }

$imploded_tags = array_unique($imploded_tags);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($imploded_tags);
```

See the manual on [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

However, I do think you are not using the right way to store your tags; they should be stored in a separate table as separate values.

Answer (score 0):

What's going on is when you're fetching your rows from MySQL, you're essentially getting a bunch of data in an array in the first place, which is why you have to loop through them.

With your your implode function, you're taking a bunch of strings, then getting another array set and then appending that to an external array.

If you really wanted to get a single dimensional array without having this multidimensional thing going on, all you really need to do is utilize another loop within that loop.

```
    $all_tags = array();
    while ($row_tags = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_tags)) { 
        $tags = $row_tags['tags'];
        $imploded_tags[] = explode("|",$tags);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($imploded_tags); $i++) {
            $all_tags[] = $imploded_tags[$i]
        }
    }
    print_r($all_tags);
```